# Oracle regexp_substr - extract substring from string comes in different formats

Tags: sql, regex, database, oracle

I have a string that comes in different formats like these:

```
UserId=1;IP Address=85.154.221.54;Device Type=Chrome57
Device Type=Chrome57;IP Address=85.154.221.54
Device Type=Chrome57
```

How can I extract the IP Address and return empty string if there is no match ?

I have tried the following, but it return the string itself if there is no match.

```
select regexp_replace('Error=0;UserId=-1;IP Address=85.154.221.54;Device Type=Chrome57', '.*IP Address=(.+);.*', '\1') from dual;
```

Comment: Empty string or is *NULL* fine?

Comment: both works for me

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is Oracle so an empty string is null.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Actually, I have seen some questions where OP asked specifically for an "empty string". So, I just wanted to make that clear so as to avoid any further terminological and other "disputes".

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - ah, I see what you mean now :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle SQL - Get rows with values in IP address format (dotted quad)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29511621/oracle-sql-get-rows-with-values-in-ip-address-format-dotted-quad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` with your slightly improved pattern:

```
select regexp_substr('Error=0;UserId=-1;IP Address=85.154.221.54;Device Type=Chrome57',
                     'IP Address=([0-9.]+)',
                     1, 1, NULL, 1
                    )
from dual
```

Here,

- `IP Address=` - matches `IP Address=`
- `([0-9.]+)` - matches and captures into Group 1 one or more digits or/and `.`

See an [online demo](http://rextester.com/TJKLK16795). If there is no match, the output will be *NULL*.

```
select regexp_substr('Error=0;UserId=-1;IP Address=85.154.221.54;Device Type=Chrome57',
                     'IP Address=([0-9.]+)',
                     1, 1, NULL, 1
                    ) as Result
from dual
-- => 85.154.221.54
--select regexp_substr('Error=0;UserId=-1;IP Address= Device Type=Chrome57', 'IP Address=([0-9.]+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) as result from dual
-- => NULL
```

[image]

Note that the last `1` argument to `REGEXP_SUBSTR` function returns the contents of capturing group #1 (text captured with the first parenthesized part of the pattern).

Comment: Doesn't work if the IP is at the end without ' ; ' , try the second string

Comment: @BilalHalayqa That is because *your* pattern did not account for that. Remove `;` at the end, and it will.